# Redirect to index only parent route

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to find a way to redirect to the index route if access the parent  route but not redirect if a user access the parent.child1 or parent.child2 route.

Is something like this possible?

```
this.route('parent', function() {
      this.route('child1');
      this.route('child2');
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you could describe your problem and how you think this may solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

> If the user is in the `parent` route but not in the `child1` and not in the `child2` route redirect to the `index` route.

For this you need to understand that you have an implicit `parent.index` route. So with your route definition, this are your routes:

- `index`
- `parent.index`
- `parent.child1`
- `parent.child2`

You can't just be in the route `parent`! You are always either in `parent.index`, `parent.child1`, or `parent.child2`.

So I think what you want is to redirect from `parent.index` to `index`.

For this just create the `app/routes/parent/index.js` route, and in the `beforeModel` hook call `this.transitionTo('index');`.

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

<del>Put your redirect condition inside `parent` route's `beforeModel` hook.</del>

Please refer to Lux's answer. Create a `index` route under your parent route using,

```
ember g route parent/index
```

And then put your redirection logic inside the parent/index route's `beforeModel` hook.

My previous answer wont work because it block child route from entering.

Comment: This will prevent you from entering `child1` or `child2`.

Comment: Can the route only redirect when certain contione met otherwise do nothing?

Comment: Yes, Lux you are right he can also do it inside `parent.index` route. However, in that case he has to generate a new `index` route since it does not exist yet.

Comment: Well, you *can* check a condition, but you don't have the sub-route name available in the `beforeModel` hook. Checking a condition however is useful for authentication.

Comment: I was thinking I have the FULL url so that I can redirect based on that. nevertheless your solution is a better one.